# Is there any way to detect deadlock programmatically on iOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to bulid a debug toolchain for my projects, I used the ping pong between main thread and other thread to detect if the main thread has been stucked. But I came across a situation, when the main thread dead lock, this approach doesn't work. I am looking for an method to detect deadlock programmatically on iOS. I'll be appreciated if anybody can give me some advice on this issue.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637454/deadlocks-how-do-you-determine-if-a-call-may-cause-unsafe-painting-off-of-the-m

Comment: did you have answer for it at nowadays?